# Systrace Error - Analysis slices Table Not displaying on HTML Page

Tags: android, html, linux, performance, systrace

I have ran Systrace in Linux and generated a HTML. The HTML file got generated fine with the content. 
Here comes my problem : When I have selected a portion of the content in the HTML at the end of the page there should be a **Analysis slices Table** which needs to be displayed. But it is not displaying.

I tried in both Chrome and Chromium but it dint worked anywhere.

Can anyone please suggest what might be the issue ?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. In earlier versions of Chrome the selected slice info was displaying properly. But with the latest version(ver.45) with beta version(ver46) and with dev version(ver.47) it is not working.

Also, I see in the chrome console that "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History' " error. Please let me know if you find some solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. I used latest chrome (45.0.2454.85 m (64-bit)) and updated my android platform tools in the SDK to 23+ version. Now the systrace dump shows the selected slice info perfectly.